# OK to use residual sum of squares for cross-validation of binary outcome?

Tags: regression, logistic, cross-validation, validation, scoring-rules

For an OLS model the mean squared error can be used to assess the fit of the trained model on the validation data.

What is the equivalent for a logistic regression model? Can I simply use the following residual sum of squares function?

$RSS=\Sigma^N_{i=1}(y_i-{\hat p})^2$

Comment: How about using classification rate?

Answer (score 1):

What you propose is equivalent to using the [Brier score](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/255747/how-to-decide-the-best-accuracy-score-for-prediction-of-binary-outcome) which is a [proper scoring rule](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/126965/justifying-and-choosing-a-proper-scoring-rule).  So it is certainly OK to use it for cross-validation.

See also [logistic regression predictive modeling](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/193867/logistic-regression-predictive-modeling).